# Error LessError: Cannot find module, because of npm install(update), package module Dependencies update

Tags: node.js, npm, antd, ant-design-pro

## Summarize

with clone a git repo, `npm install` to install modules, and then ```npm run'''  this demo with error like this

```
Error occurred compiling file D:/git/www_front/src/pages/Version/index.less
Error LessError: Cannot find module '@/utils/utils.less' from
```

## Describe

with try some times , find this module's `antd-pro-theme-webpack-plugin` requires `antd-theme-generator` was update, may i get an answer to resolve this bug.
may i know , how do you control package.joso dependense version, with ^ , @ or just hard it?

this is part of package.json and package-lock.josn file

## file

**index.less**

```
@import '~antd/lib/style/themes/default.less';
@import '~@/utils/utils.less';
```

**package.json：**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.4.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
    "antd-pro-merge-less": "^0.0.9",
    "antd-pro-theme-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.8",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.1",
    "cross-port-killer": "^1.0.1",
}
```

**package-lock.json with bug**

```
    "antd-pro-theme-webpack-plugin": {
      "version": "1.1.8",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/antd-pro-theme-webpack-plugin/download/antd-pro-theme-webpack-plugin-1.1.8.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-iLyjkioefvIdLVfaqOLBmIYQ+dw=",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "antd-theme-generator": "^1.1.3",
        "less": "^2.7.2",
        "less-bundle-promise": "1.0.4",
        "postcss": "^6.0.21"
      }
    },
    "antd-theme-generator": {
      "version": "1.2.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/antd-theme-generator/download/antd-theme-generator-1.2.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-pro7Mq10TrpJEcJqRM58y8NpVBU=",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "glob": "^7.1.3",
        "hash.js": "^1.1.5",
        "less": "^3.9.0",
        "less-plugin-npm-import": "^2.1.0",
        "postcss": "^6.0.21",
        "strip-css-comments": "^4.1.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "less": {
          "version": "3.11.3",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/less/download/less-3.11.3.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-LYU5VPz+AWmor4aWILyqFlY9zBw=",
          "dev": true,
          "requires": {
            "clone": "^2.1.2",
            "errno": "^0.1.1",
            "graceful-fs": "^4.1.2",
            "image-size": "~0.5.0",
            "make-dir": "^2.1.0",
            "mime": "^1.4.1",
            "promise": "^7.1.1",
            "request": "^2.83.0",
            "source-map": "~0.6.0",
            "tslib": "^1.10.0"
          }
        },
        "mime": {
          "version": "1.6.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/mime/download/mime-1.6.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-Ms2eXGRVO9WNGaVor0Uqz/BJgbE=",
          "dev": true,
          "optional": true
        },
        "source-map": {
          "version": "0.6.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/source-map/download/source-map-0.6.1.tgz?cache=0&sync_timestamp=1567937985360&other_urls=https%3A%2F%2Fregistry.npm.taobao.org%2Fsource-map%2Fdownload%2Fsource-map-0.6.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-dHIq8y6WFOnCh6jQu95IteLxomM=",
          "dev": true,
          "optional": true
        }
      }
    },
```

**package-lock.json with ok verson:**

```
    "antd-pro-theme-webpack-plugin": {
      "version": "1.1.8",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/antd-pro-theme-webpack-plugin/download/antd-pro-theme-webpack-plugin-1.1.8.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-iLyjkioefvIdLVfaqOLBmIYQ+dw=",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "antd-theme-generator": "^1.1.3",
        "less": "^2.7.2",
        "less-bundle-promise": "1.0.4",
        "postcss": "^6.0.21"
      }
    },
    "antd-theme-generator": {
      "version": "1.1.9",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/antd-theme-generator/download/antd-theme-generator-1.1.9.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-dfc6VvAi2o9zMWrZ0dCKwvYoFng=",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "glob": "^7.1.3",
        "hash.js": "^1.1.5",
        "less": "^3.9.0",
        "less-bundle-promise": "1.0.7",
        "less-plugin-npm-import": "^2.1.0",
        "postcss": "^6.0.21",
        "postcss-colors-only": "0.0.3"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "less": {
          "version": "3.11.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/less/download/less-3.11.1.tgz?cache=0&sync_timestamp=1581428110523&other_urls=https%3A%2F%2Fregistry.npm.taobao.org%2Fless%2Fdownload%2Fless-3.11.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-xr8I454CQE/mswej3/+v3FW9NuI=",
          "dev": true,
          "requires": {
            "clone": "^2.1.2",
            "errno": "^0.1.1",
            "graceful-fs": "^4.1.2",
            "image-size": "~0.5.0",
            "mime": "^1.4.1",
            "mkdirp": "^0.5.0",
            "promise": "^7.1.1",
            "request": "^2.83.0",
            "source-map": "~0.6.0",
            "tslib": "^1.10.0"
          }
        },
        "less-bundle-promise": {
          "version": "1.0.7",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/less-bundle-promise/download/less-bundle-promise-1.0.7.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-GY15kaxPXzx4YvrBB0x7msp7nLI=",
          "dev": true
        },
        "mime": {
          "version": "1.6.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/mime/download/mime-1.6.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-Ms2eXGRVO9WNGaVor0Uqz/BJgbE=",
          "dev": true,
          "optional": true
        },
        "source-map": {
          "version": "0.6.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/source-map/download/source-map-0.6.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-dHIq8y6WFOnCh6jQu95IteLxomM=",
          "dev": true,
          "optional": true
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have use`npm install` outside of the project. Make sure you are on the inside of your project, then use `npm install` it should work.

Comment: i'm sure that i had run ```npm install``` with right dir,